# Rails: Amazon S3 + Paperclip not storing anything in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

Hi I'm currently making an app for users to upload pics. I'm trying to add Amazon S3 in preparation to deploy my app. I'm not getting any error, but after trying to set up Amazon S3 my pics aren't uploading properly. The pics are uploading properly onto Amazon, not in my database so that when I upload the pics and try to loop through them in the views to show them, nothing shows. Can anyone assist me?

Just as a sidenote, I'm using Paperclip + jQuery file upload (for multiple pic uploads) + Amazon S3 + a s3_direct_upload gem (https://github.com/WayneHoover/s3_direct_upload)

config routes (notice that pics is nested in albums and users) no issue here

```
Pholder::Application.routes.draw do
resources :users do
  resources :friends
  resources :albums do
    resources :photos
  end
end
end
```

users/show.html.erb (the page that is supposed to show my uploaded pics, no new pics are showing up even after my uploads)

```
    <% @user.albums.each do |album| %>
        <div class="albumthumb">
            <%= link_to image_tag(!album.photos.empty? ? album.photos.first.avatar.url(:medium) : ("questionmark.png"), :size => "150x150"), user_album_path(@user, album) %>
            <br>
            <%= album.name %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

photos/new.html.erb (issue here as well)

```
 #my new uploader that works with amazon s3, but doesn't seem to be storing the pics in my database
<%= s3_uploader_form post: user_album_photos_path, as: "photo[avatar]", id: "myS3Uploader" do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file, multiple: true %>
<% end %>

#this is my old upload form that worked fine when uploading pics to my local public directory. 
#
#<% provide(:title, "Upload pictures") %>
#
#<%= form_for([@user, @album, @photo], :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
#
#<%= f.file_field :avatar, multiple: true, name: "photo[avatar]" %>


<div id="pics">
    <%= render :partial => "photo", :collection => @photos %>
</div>

<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
<div class="upload">
  {%=o.name%}
  <div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width: 0%"></div></div>
</div>
</script>
```

Here's my code on github: https://github.com/EdmundMai/railstest/blob/master/app/views/photos/new.html.erb

Let me know if you need me to upload any more code. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery file upload just uploads the files to Amazon S3: it doesn't add the required Paperclip records to the database. To do that, you need to do a few more steps. See the [jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example) or [jQuery File Upload v4 for Rails 3](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/jQuery-File-Upload-v4-for-Rails-3).

Comment: thanks Max, I'll check it out now and let you know in a few min

Comment: could you perhaps give me some guidance on which part of the mvc I should be looking at? the html form looks quite complicated to me. Do you suggest I stop using the s3_direct_upload gem?

Comment: It certainly is easier to use the usual form upload method to interface with Paperclip. However, JQuery File Upload does have a lot of neat features like multiple uploads, drag-and-drop, progress indicators, etc. So if you want those features, then adding the extra Javascript code to make it work with Paperclip is probably worth it.

Comment: Take a look at [jQuery File Upload v4 for Rails 3](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/jQuery-File-Upload-v4-for-Rails-3) it has a pretty straightforward explanation of what is needed.

Comment: I realized I had an earlier form that I made that actually worked... !!! Thanks for the help